# passing textbox value from a parent window to a page wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, data-binding, mvvm

No doubt I'm not the first to ask something of this nature. The thing is for the majority of these, the replies will lay reference to MVVM when it comes to wpf and not really explain how that's done or give an applicable example at the very least. The rest are specific to those peoples particular situations.

Imagine I have a textbox in the main window and I also have one in a page. I need the text in the textbox in the Main window to be passed onto the textbox in the child window. How's that done?

The method used in winforms appears to only work on window to window. It throws an exception though every time you enter a value in the page declaration and run it.

Pages are opened via links, If its of any use, I'm using the modern ui theme for wpf: http://mui.codeplex.com

Main window xaml

```
  <mui:ModernWindow x:Class="Masca.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
Title="Masca Database Admin" Height="800" Width="1280" IsTitleVisible="True"
LogoData="F1 M 24.9015,43.0378L 25.0963,43.4298C 26.1685,49.5853 31.5377,54.2651 38,54.2651C 44.4623,54.2651 49.8315,49.5854 50.9037,43.4299L 51.0985,43.0379C 51.0985,40.7643 52.6921,39.2955 54.9656,39.2955C 56.9428,39.2955 58.1863,41.1792 58.5833,43.0379C 57.6384,52.7654 47.9756,61.75 38,61.75C 28.0244,61.75 18.3616,52.7654 17.4167,43.0378C 17.8137,41.1792 19.0572,39.2954 21.0344,39.2954C 23.3079,39.2954 24.9015,40.7643 24.9015,43.0378 Z M 26.7727,20.5833C 29.8731,20.5833 32.3864,23.0966 32.3864,26.197C 32.3864,29.2973 29.8731,31.8106 26.7727,31.8106C 23.6724,31.8106 21.1591,29.2973 21.1591,26.197C 21.1591,23.0966 23.6724,20.5833 26.7727,20.5833 Z M 49.2273,20.5833C 52.3276,20.5833 54.8409,23.0966 54.8409,26.197C 54.8409,29.2973 52.3276,31.8106 49.2273,31.8106C 46.127,31.8106 43.6136,29.2973 43.6136,26.197C 43.6136,23.0966 46.127,20.5833 49.2273,20.5833 Z"          
ContentSource="/Pages/Home.xaml">
```

Child window xaml

```
  <UserControl x:Class="Masca.Mail.Configuration"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1280">
```

```
<TextBox x:Name="alias" Margin="186,64,0,0" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="211" FontSize="11" ></TextBox>
```

I am doing this so that the program will know which user is logging in ang can log who is making what changes to the database.

Comment: Why cant you use data binding between the two textboxes?

Comment: Im trying that. No doubt it works well in the same page... but i dont know how to do it across different pages. I've heard the suggestion of using a viewmodel singleton class but there's no explanation i can find on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

How I will do that is to set the `DataContext` property of second page to the first page. Then I can access the properties of first page in second page via Binding. For this its better to use MVVM in your application and then define the property in ViewModel of Page 1 and then define `DataContext` in page 2. Now you can access that property in page 2.